# How can I test my GPU RAM integrity?

Tags: memory, graphics, gpu, memtest

I would like to use something like memtest86 but for VRAM. I have some artifacts on the screen some times and I'm trying to rule out possibilities.

Comment: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/having-problems-with-video-card-stress-test-its-memory/ - some of them are not for Linux, but that shouldn't be a problem if you really want to test it.

Comment: the issue I need a memory tester not a stress test.

Answer (score 7):

Dicslosure: I'm an author of the program linked below, so my opinion can be weighted

[memtest_vulkan](https://github.com/GpuZelenograd/memtest_vulkan) is small & simple open-source tool for stress-testing gpu memory on any vulkan 1.1 compatible GPU. Linux binaries transparently available from github actions artifacts

https://github.com/GpuZelenograd/memtest_vulkan/releases

Building binaries via github actions is configured. So... anybody can fork repo->enable workflows on the actions tab->make any small changes you want even via browser->commit and github will build the binary artifacts from changes you make for you personally!

Example of ok run [image: No errors]

Example of run with errros [image: Has errors]

Answer (score 2):

There is an OpenCL-based memory tester called [MemtestCL](https://github.com/ihaque/memtestCL) which can do this:

> MemtestCL is a program to test the memory and logic of OpenCL-enabled
> GPUs, CPUs, and accelerators for errors. It is an OpenCL port of our
> CUDA- based tester for NVIDIA GPUs, MemtestG80.
>
> This is the open-source version of MemtestCL, implementing the same
> memory tests as the closed-source version. The intended usage is as a
> library so that other software developers can use the MemtestCL tests
> to validate the correct operation of GPUs or accelerators in their own
> code. In addition to the core memory testing libraries, this package
> contains the source code to a limited version of the command-line
> interface standalone tester included in the closed- source build;
> certain capabilities, such as the ability to transmit results back to
> Stanford, are not present in the open-source version.
>
> Up-to-date versions of both the closed- and open-source versions of
> MemtestCL may be downloaded at https://simtk.org/home/memtest. The
> closed-source version is available as precompiled binaries; the
> open-source version is available only as a source package.